# Setting up restful routes as a total newb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I'm getting the following error:

Unknown action

No action responded to show. Actions: activate, destroy, index, org_deals, search, and suspend

Controller:

```
class Admin::HomepagesController < Admin::ApplicationController

def org_deals
@organization = Organization.find(:all)
end
```

Routes:

```
   map.root :controller => 'main'
   map.admin '/admin', :controller => 'admin/main'

   map.namespace :admin do |admin|
   admin.resources :organizations, :collection => {:search => :get}, :member => {:suspend => :get, :activate => :get}
```

To note: This is a controller inside of a controller.

Any idea why this is defaulting to show?

Update:

I updated what the routes syntax is. Read that article, and tried quite a few variations but its still adamantly looking for a show.

Comment: I can hack this by just changing my view to the word 'show' , but why is it defaulting to show?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, it looks like your `routes` file has the wrong syntax. If you are trying to establish  routes for nested resources, you'd do it like so:

```
map.resources :admin
  admin.resources :organizations
end
```

This would give you paths such as:

```
/admin/
/admin/1
/admin/1/organizations
/admin/1/organizations/1
```

The mapping from route to controller/action is done via a Rails convention, where HTTP verbs are assigned in ways that are useful for the typical CRUD operations. For example:

```
/admin/1/organizations/1
```

would map to several actions in the OrganizationsController, distinguished by the type of verb:

```
/admin/1/organizations/1 # GET -> :action => :show
/admin/1/organizations/1 # PUT -> :action => :update
/admin/1/organizations/1 # DELETE -> :action => :destroy
```

"Show" is one of the seven standard resourceful actions that Rails gives you by default. You can exclude "show" with the directive `:except => :show`, or specify only the resourceful actions you want with `:only => :update`, for example.

I recommend you look at [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html), which is a great introduction to this topic.

**EDIT**

I see I ignored the namespacing in my answer, sorry. How about this:

```
  map.namespace(:admin) do |admin|
    admin.resources :homepages, :member => { :org_deals => :get }
  end
```

This will generate your `org_deals` action as a GET with an id parameter (for the organization). You also get a `show` route, along with the six other resourceful routes. `rake routes` shows this:

```
org_deals_admin_homepage GET /admin/homepages/:id/org_deals(.:format) {:controller=>"admin/homepages", :action=>"org_deals"}
```

Of course your `homepages_controller.rb` has to live in `app/controllers/admin/`

**EDIT** *redux*

Actually, you want `organizations` in the path, I'll bet, in which case:

```
  map.namespace(:admin) do |admin|
    admin.resources :organizations, :controller => :homepages, :member => { :org_deals => :get }
  end
```

which gives you:

```
org_deals_admin_organization GET    /admin/organizations/:id/org_deals(.:format) {:controller=>"admin/homepages", :action=>"org_deals"}
```

Comment: I had posted the wrong syntax. I updated it above. I'm think that that somehow member and collection is overriding the normal action going on. Not sure..

Comment: Yes, you have an amazing response. Absolutely. My objective is probably not so RESTful as I'm just trying to create a side view that has nothing to do with CRUD. In this case, I tried making a 'named route' within a loop. admin.namespace :organizations do |organization| <break> organization.org_deals 'org_deals', :controller => 'organizations', :action => 'org_deals' <break> end  . But this still defaults to a show. I assume I need to add member in there. I tried your's adding org_deals to member but it's looking for an Org /:id/ which it doesn't need because its irrelevant to them specificall

Comment: If you don't want the :id, don't use resources -- just create a named route, or use `map.connect`

Comment: admin.namespace :organizations do |organization|
      organization.org_deals 'org_deals', :action => 'org_deals'
    end

This creates in rake routes, the proper link, but it's still looking for the show action when it loads the path. 
I also tried the connect way too. Routes were right, but it still looked for show.

Answer (score 0):

By specifying `admin.resources ...` you are telling Rails you want the seven default different routes in your application. If you do not want them, and only want the ones you specify, do not use `.resources`. Show is called because that's the default route called for a GET request with a path such as `/admin/id` when you have the default resources.

Comment: so could i write something like this then 'admin.org_deals 'org_deals', :controller => 'admin/organizations/', :action => 'org_deals' . And if so, would the path be, 'org_deals_admin_organization_path ?